# why I see the background of the div under the canvas

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to scroll a canvas inside a div. The problem that when I try to scroll I see a red line part of the red background of the div below instead I would expect to see everything entirely black.

HTML:

```
   <div id="Div1" style=" float: left; width: 150px; height: 200px; background: red; overflow:scroll; ">
    <canvas id="myCanvas1" width="200px" height="500px" style="border:0px solid #ff0000;">asdf asd as asfqwe asd asdfasdf asd as asfqwe asd asdfasdf asd as asfqwe asd asdf</canvas>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
 var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas1");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 500);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#00ff00";  //<======= here
    ctx.font = '35px serif';
    ctx.fillText('Hello world', 0, 40);
```

CSS:

```
canvas { border: 0px solid black; }
```

This is a minimal example:
https://jsfiddle.net/alessio211734/vL4whdc0/17/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/alessio211734/vL4whdc0/17/

Comment: Apart from that your fiddle link only gives me a 404 - code relevant to your question belongs directly _into_ your question, in text form and properly formatted, not just dumped on an external site. Please edit accordingly.

Comment: please add  another reference to the code the above link is dead

Comment: I have fix the link, now work

Comment: Because a canvas a treated as an image, add `vertical-align:middle` and the space below is gone.

Comment: A canvas is an inline element by default; if you add `display: block;` to its CSS, it will be positioned exactly within the background div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add     `display: block;` to `canvas`

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas1");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 500);
ctx.fillStyle = "#00ff00"; //<======= here
ctx.font = '35px serif';
ctx.fillText('Hello world', 0, 40);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 0px solid black;
display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="Div1" style=" float: left; width: 150px; height: 200px; background: red; overflow:scroll; ">
<canvas id="myCanvas1" width="200px" height="500px" style="border:0px solid #ff0000;">asdf asd as asfqwe asd asdfasdf asd as asfqwe asd asdfasdf asd as asfqwe asd asdf</canvas>
</div>
```